# DOS execution of assembly code

Tags: assembly, dos, tsr

I'm writing a chunk of assembly that will register a tsr and then exit.

I'm struggling to figure out how to properly assemble this to a format that I can execute in dos.

i'm have access to ubuntu 9.04 and windows xp. (linux method is preffered). If anyone can tell me how i go about assembling my code into a dos executable format, and then how i execute it in dos i'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: TSR's?  DOS?  Suddenly it's 1985 all over again.  Does XP even support TSR's?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/dosonly.mspx?mfr=true  I guess you can still do this.  Amazing.

Comment: Now I'm curious - what does your tsr do? Or is it just a learning experience?

Comment: its just for learning. i've been taking assembly classes at school and want to mess with actually using some of the knowledge.

Comment: @ZJR DOS is still somewhat common in some embedded x86 systems where you want the benefits of an operating system with the flexibility of bare-metal access to the hardware.

Comment: be warned, while assembly programming may look somewhat easy, assembling a working TSR which actually works without crashing require a very extensive knowledge of DOS and its inner workings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incase anyone else happens upon here with the same question I had here is the answer I finally found. Its a free development environment that allows for easily making dos programs:

http://www.winasm.net/

the dev environment does all the backend work using masm so that has to be installed also but it handles all of the assembly and linking.

Answer (score 1):

If it's for a .COM executable, you just need an "org 0x100" at the start and assemble with "nasm -f bin", using nasm built for any OS.

For an .EXE you need a DOS linker, ie. the one which comes with TASM/MASM.  I'm not sure if there is a portable 16-bit DOS linker, most tend to link 32-bit programs which run under a DOS-Extender.

Comment: okay i was able to assemble with nasm but i'm confused on the linking portion. i downloaded masm and am trying to figure out how to link it

Answer (score 1):

IF you are using masm, then there is a 16 bit linker available ...http://blogs.pcworld.com/communityvoices/archives/2007/10/using_masm32_wi.html - should help you.

Comment: (http://web.archive.org/web/20071013092543/http://blogs.pcworld.com:80/communityvoices/archives/2007/10/using_masm32_wi.html)